# MATCH IN BOOLEAN MODE doesn't match an existing record?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

So I've got this seemingly simple query:

```
SELECT i.*, 
    g.title AS groupname, 
    c.name AS category, 
    v.name AS author, 
    w.name as moderator, 
    u.name AS editor 
FROM `jos_k2_items` as i 
    LEFT JOIN `jos_k2_categories` AS c ON c.id = i.catid 
    LEFT JOIN `jos_viewlevels` AS g ON g.id = i.access 
    LEFT JOIN `jos_users` AS u ON u.id = i.checked_out 
    LEFT JOIN `jos_users` AS v ON v.id = i.created_by 
    LEFT JOIN `jos_users` AS w ON w.id = i.modified_by 
WHERE i.trash=0 
    AND MATCH( i.title ) AGAINST ('+red* +2*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY i.id DESC
```

built by the Joomla search in the administrator interface. I'm trying to find an article named `RED 2`, but it's not returning any results. Below is a snippet of the row:

```
id  title   alias   catid   published ... trash
===============================================
800 RED 2   red-2   5       1             0
```

There are **two** full text indexes on the table. The first is on the `title` column and the second is on `title, introtext, fulltext, extra_fields_search, image_caption, image_credits, video_caption, video_credits, metadesc, metakey`.

One of the things I tried was to rebuild the index, I used the following command:

```
REPAIR TABLE `jos_k2_items` QUICK;
```

Comment: your search words are to small, by default the minimum is 3 (`ft_min_word_len = 3`)

Comment: @Dagon, alright so you're absolutely correct. Is there a way to override that? These are legitimate articles that the client needs to be able to find, and they have thousands of them, so going through page-by-page isn't really an option.

Comment: yes, you can change the value of `ft_min_word_len` - assuming you have control over the mysql server. restart, AND index rebuild required

Comment: @Dagon: okay I believe I found the configuration setting here, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html, right?

Comment: yup that's the one, don't forget restart and index rebuild (`REPAIR TABLE my_table QUICK;`)

Comment: @Dagon, add these processes as the answer and I'll accept.

Comment: done, feel free to edit the answer to make it better for future question finders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your trying to match words shorter than the default minimum full text index length of 3

first change that limit

```
ft_min_word_len = 3
```

to 2 or 1.

then restart mysql, and rebuild the index on the table:

you can do that with:

```
REPAIR TABLE my_table QUICK;
```